# php - using strpos() to replace multiple comparisons in an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, strpos

Is it OK to replace multiple comparisons by using strpos()?
Example:
changing

```
if ( $linecounter == $extra1 || $linecounter == $extra2 || $linecounter == 5 )
{ 
  ...
}
```

to

```
$ok = ' ' . $extra1 . $extra2 . '5';
if ( strpos($ok, $linecounter) > 0 )
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not OK because that's not what `strpos` is for. It's easy to find problematic examples in the general case (e.g. `$linecounter == 15` and `$extra2 == 1` -- the `strpos` check will succeed when it should not have).

If you want to lose the separate conditions so much, workable alternatives would be either a `switch` statement or `in_array`:

```
switch($linecounter) {
    case $extra1: case $extra2: case 5:
        // whatever
        break;
}

if (in_array($linecounter, [$extra1, $extra2, 5])) {
    // whatever
}
```

As an aside, using `strpos` with a greater-than-zero test like that is not good style. What you want to say is "if it's found in the string", so write exactly that and lose the "prefix a space" hack:

```
if ( strpos($extra1 . $extra2 . '5', $linecounter) !== false )
```

Comment: This way you can also build more scalable applications by simply adding a value in array instead of rewriting the string or regular expression. (And avoid false positives.)

Comment: I'll use the **in_array()** solution. I knew using **strpos()** was not elegant, but didn't know how to fix it.  Thank you!